# MySql insert going in with null values with HTML encoded parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have created a database with tables I am trying to insert my parameterized query which is HTML encoded into the table. I need a loop that can identify which parameter to add depending on the data in the query. The loop executes just fine and on debugging all the proper data is being placed in the parameters correctly. However, once the query executes and I check the DB I see a new record has been added but all the values for all the columns are null or empty.

I am not able to see why if the proper data is being sent and no errors are coming back why blank data would input. Any ideas?

Here is my code:
The Query:

```
INSERT into alerts (`emailAddress`,`authorName`,`alertSubj`,`alertBody`,`email`,`alertExpires`,`releaseDateTime`)
VALUES (@emailAddress,@authorName,@alertSubj,@alertBody,@email,@alertExpires,@releaseDateTime);
```

Image of elements in the valueArray:

```
emailAddress
authorName
alertSubj
alertBody
email
alertExpires
releaseDateTime
```

Loop for the parameters:

```
foreach(String data in valueArray)
            {
                    String paraName = "\"";
                        paraName+="@" + valueArray[p];
                        paraName += "\"";
                    switch (valueArray[p])
                    {
                        case "emailAddress":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(emailAddress));
                        break;
                        case "twitter":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(twitter));
                        break;
                        case "email":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email));
                        break;
                        case"sms":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text));
                        break;
                        case "desktop":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(desktop));
                        break;
                        case "playSound":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(voice));
                        break;
                        case"releaseDateTime":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(releaseDate_Time));
                        break;
                        case "alertExpires":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(expiresDate_Time));
                        break;
                        case "alertSubj":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(alertSubject));
                        break;
                        case "alertBody":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(emailBody));
                        break;
                        case "shortMsgBody":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(shortAlert));
                        break;
                        case"authorName":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(author));
                        break;
                        case "criticality":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraName, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(level));
                        break;
                        default:
                        break;
                    }                   
                    p++;                  
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add quotes to parameter name. Instead of

```
String paraName = "\"";
       paraName+="@" + valueArray[p];
       paraName += "\"";
```

Just do

```
String paraName = "@" + valueArray[p];
```

Also since you're already looping thru your array - there's no need to add another counter. You can do something like

```
 foreach (String data in valueArray)
 {
     switch (data)
     {
         case "emailAddress":
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + data, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(emailAddress));
              break;
                ....
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent days trying different scenarios and swear I thought I tried removing the quotes but I think in general I was making that small area more complicated then it needed to be.